# Сколько различных аннотаций (annotations) доступно в Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, аннотации

Я новичек в objective-c, затронул Nullability Annotations и стало интересно, сколько в этом языке  различных аннотаций доступно вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, вас интересуют возможные атрибуты свойств. Существуют следующие:

- Атрибуты доступности (`readonly`/`readwrite`)
- Атрибуты владения (`strong`/`weak`/`unsafe_unretained`/`copy`/`retain`/`assign`)
- Атрибуты атомарности (`nonatomic`/`atomic`)
- Атрибуты nullability (`nonnull`/`nullable`/`null_unspecified`/`null_resettable`)
- Атрибуты для указания геттеров/сеттеров (`getter`/`setter`)
- Атрибут принадлежности к классу (`class`)